# db2 sql : get days between two strings that represent date in 'yyyy/mm/dd' format

Tags: db2

I googled and found nothing helpful

---

according @bluish's answer, I had solved my problem:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "ALS6FD"."DAYSBETWEEN"
(date1 VARCHAR(10),date2 VARCHAR(10)) RETURNS INTEGER LANGUAGE SQL 
BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE
sAmount INTEGER;
SET sAmount =
(
 DAYS( SUBSTR(date1,1,4) || '-' || SUBSTR(date1,6,2) || '-' || SUBSTR(date1,9,2) ) -
 DAYS( SUBSTR(date2,1,4) || '-' || SUBSTR(date2,6,2) || '-' || SUBSTR(date2,9,2) )
)
;
RETURN sAmount;
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  DAYS(SUBSTR(DATE2,1,4) || '-' || SUBSTR(DATE2,6,2) || '-' || SUBSTR(DATE2,9,2))
    -
  DAYS(SUBSTR(DATE1,1,4) || '-' || SUBSTR(DATE1,6,2) || '-' || SUBSTR(DATE1,9,2))
FROM TABLE
```